# POWER BI - How to add manual columns/data to existing table instead of adding columns/data to the source csv file

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

The picture I have attached shows what my power query table looks like (exactly the same as source file) and then underneath what I would like the final end product to look like.
Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought the purpose of power query/power bi was to not manipulate the source file but do this in power query/power bi?
If that's the case, how can I enter new columns and data to the existing table below?

[image: ORIGINAL TABLE VS END PRODUCT]

Comment: I should clarify that I want to MANUALLY add data into an existing table.

Comment: the columns that you are trying to add, Weighing Type,Mob Type & Mob , Is it static or does the value change based on any other column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom columns without manipulating source file in power bi. Please refer to below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-add-custom-column

**EDIT**: Based on your comment editing my answer - Not sure if this helps.

Click on edit queries after loading source file to power bi.

**Using 'Enter Data' button**  entered sample data you provided  and created new table. Data can be copy pasted from excel. You can enter new rows manually. Using Tag number column to keep reference.
[image]

**Merge Queries** - Once the above table is created merged it with original table on tag number column.

[image]

**Expand Table** - In the original table expand the merged table. Uncheck tag number(as it is already present) and uncheck use original column name as prefix.
[image]

Now the table will look like the way you wanted it.

[image]

You can always change data(add new columns/rows) manually in new table by clicking on gear button next to source.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply srinivasu.  I should have clarified that I'm trying to enter data MANUALLY therefore this is more complicated than adding a column. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hi, is the answer that provind help? With this query you can create an empty column and specify the value of each row without issues.

Comment: Hi Srinivasu - I'll give the above a go...I think this should work!! Fingers crossed and thanks again all for helping.  I'll let you know asap

Comment: Hi srinivasu -  this worked perfectly!!  Thanks very much for your help with this.  Greatly appreciated!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest solution to what I found from "manual data entry" letting you as much freedom as you would like to add rows of data, if the columns that you want to create do not follow a specific pattern.

I used an example for the column "Mob". I have not exactly reproduced the content of your cells but I hope that this will not be an issue to understand the logic.

Here is the data I am starting with:

[image]

Here is the Power Query in which I "manually" add a row:

```
  #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Mob", each if [Tag Number] = "v" then null else null),
    NewRows = Table.InsertRows(#"Added Conditional Column", 2, {[Mob="15-OHIO", Tag Number="4353654", Electronic ID=1.5, NLIS="", Date="31/05/2015", Live Weight="6", Draft="", Condition store="", Weighing Type="WEAN"]})
in
    NewRows
```

**1)** I first created a column with only null values:

```
  #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Mob", each if [Tag Number] = "v" then null else null),
```

**2)** With the **"Table.InsertRows"** function:

- I indicated the specific line: 2, (knowing that power Bi start counting at zero, at the "headers" so it will the third line in the file)
- I indicated the column at which I wanted to insert the value, i.e "Mob"
- I indicated the value that all other other rows should have:

  ```
    NewRows = Table.InsertRows(#"Added Conditional Column", 2, {[Mob="15-OHIO", Tag Number="4353654", Electronic ID=1.5, NLIS="", Date="31/05/2015", Live Weight="6", Draft="", Condition store="", Weighing Type="WEAN"]})
  ```

Here is the result:
[image]

I hope this helps.
You can apply this logic for all the other rows.

I do not think that this is very scalable however, becaue you have to indicate each time the values of the rows in the other columns as well. There might be a better option.

Comment: Hi Tomas, thankyou very much for all of your input.  I've come up with some sort of error. I probably haven't explained myself well enough.  I think I may need to work out another way of doing this.

Comment: Do not hesitate to share your steps in the advandced editor so that we can fix it. Keep in mind that I did what I did with a reduced sample of your data and that you need to adapt it.